# Chained Throwing Futures in SwiftNIO & Vapor

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor, swift5, swift-nio

In Vapor 4, I'm processing a post request by calling a request on a 3rd party API and returning a value based on the result I get back.  The following code results in the error: "Invalid conversion from throwing function ... to non-throwing function"

```
 app.post("activate") { req -> EventLoopFuture<ActivationRequestResponse> in

        return req.client.post("https://api.example.com/activation", headers: HTTPHeaders(), beforeSend: { (req) in
            try req.content.encode(RequestBody(value: someValue), as: .json)
        })

        .map { (response) -> ActivationRequestResponse in

            let response = try response.content.decode(ResponseModel.self)
            return ActivationRequestResponse(success: true, message: "success")

        }

    }
```

I can't seem to use `try` in my chained `map()` after getting the API result.  The above code will work if I add a `!` to the `try` in `let response = try response.content.decode(ResponseModel.self)` inside the map, but ideally I want to catch this error.  The first `try` used when creating the response body seems to be implicitly passed back up the chain, but not the second.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I catch the error when decoding the response content?  Why is the first `try` caught but not the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property of `map` is that it will just transform a value on the “success path”. Your transformation may however fail which means that you presumably want the future to fail too.

Whenever you want to transform a value with a function that either succeeds or fails you need to use one of the `flatMap*` functions.

In your case, try replacing `map` with `flatMapThrowing` and then it should work.

Comment: It looks like flatMapThrowing can only be used to return a non-future.  Suppose I need to return a future with another network call.  Is there are way to transform a value that either succeeds or fails and then return a future?

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Johannes Weiss' answer, to have a throwing closure that returns a future, you need something like:

```
future.flatMap {
    do {
        return try liveDangerously()
    } catch {
        future.eventLoop.makeFailedFuture(error)
    }
}
```

After doing this too many times, I decided to roll my own (though the name is a bit dubious):

```
extension EventLoopFuture {
    @inlinable
    public func flatterMapThrowing<NewValue>(file: StaticString = #file,
            line: UInt = #line,
            _ callback: @escaping (Value) throws -> EventLoopFuture<NewValue>) -> EventLoopFuture<NewValue> {
        return self.flatMap(file: file, line: line) { (value: Value) -> EventLoopFuture<NewValue> in
            do {
                return try callback(value)
            } catch {
                return self.eventLoop.makeFailedFuture(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way you can just write:

```
future.flatterMapThrowing {
    return try liveDangerously()
}
```

Comment: In newer version, you don't need to do this. Now, there is `tryFlatMap`.

Comment: Excellent! Both a better name than mine, and a validation that the underlying idea made sense.